# How to convert numbers in a string into actual numbers

Tags: python

i have been given a string of numbers and have been tasked to reproduce only the numbers in the string with a funcion that prints within the function which i was able to do with the following.

```
# function that prints, no return the values in list
def reprint (f) :
    for numbers in (f):
        tokens = numbers.split(',')
        for values in tokens :

            print values,
        print


#Main        
stringlist =["1,25,999",
             "123.4,56.7890,13.571",
             "1,23.45,6,7.8"]

reprint (stringlist)
```

Returns

```
1 25 999
123.4 56.7890 13.571
1 23.45 6 7.8
```

The trick though is for floats to print with 2 decimal places and thats where i get stuck. I tried to add something like

```
if '.' in values :
    print "%.2f" % (values)
else print "%d" % (values)
```

but that didnt work, i get an error saying that print "3%d" % (values)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str. Any ideas on how to get the string treated as numbers?

EXPECTED Output =

```
1 25 999
123.40 56.79 13.57
1 23.45 6 7.80
```

Comment: no sort of conversion methods can be used. The guy stressed the if '.' in part so im guessing thats a part of the trick

Comment: `print "3%d" % (float(values))` and similarly `int()` for the second case

Comment: if string contains `.` convert it to float using `float()` if not, use `int()`

Comment: That's one heck of a bad format of input

Comment: @ZachSantiago: what do you mean `no sort of conversion methods can be used`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `ast.literal_eval` to convert those strings into tuple of integers and floats and then use `isinstance` to check whether it's an `int` or `float`:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
for item in stringlist:
    tup =  literal_eval(item)
    for x in tup:
        if isinstance(x, float):
            print format(x, '.2f'),
        elif isinstance(x, int):
            print format(x, 'd'),
    print
...     
1 25 999
123.40 56.79 13.57
1 23.45 6 7.80
```

Comment: Is it safe for arbitrary user input?

Comment: @livskiy Yes, see `help(ast.literal_eval)` -- > *Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression...*

Answer (score 0):

Use `float()` to convert to float number and `int()` to convert to an integer one.

```
if '.' in values :
   print "%.2f" % float(values)
else:
   print "%d" % int(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
print values,
```

with

```
if '.' in values:
   print '%.2f' % float(values),
else:
   print values,
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> stringlist
['1,25,999', '123.4,56.7890,13.571', '1,23.45,6,7.8']
>>> for line in stringlist:
...     for s in line.split(','):
...         if '.' in s:
...             try:
...                 f=float(s)
...             except ValueError:
...                 print '{} is not a float'
...             else:
...                 print '{:.2f}'.format(f),
...         else:
...             try:
...                 i=int(s)
...             except ValueError:    
...                 print '{} is not an int'.format(s)
...             else:
...                 print i,
...      print
```